# Dictionary requires a model item of type error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am getting the following error.

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MYAPP.Models.User]', but this
>   dictionary requires a model item of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[MYAPP.Models.ViewModel.AccountViewModel]'.

My code is as follows:

**VIEWMODEL**

```
public class AccountViewModel
{
    ...
    public IQueryable<User> user { get; set; }
}
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
public class UserController : Controller
{
    private REc db = new REc();

    // GET: /User/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        AccountViewModel avm = new AccountViewModel();
        var users = db.Users.Include(u => u.USERROLE);
        avm.user = users;
        return View((avm.user).ToList());
    }
```

**VIEW**

```
@model IEnumerable<SNAPAPP.Models.ViewModel.AccountViewModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
    <table class="table">
    <tr>

        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.USERROLE)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>

        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.USERROLE)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ID })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your razor view is strongly typed to a collection of `AccountViewModel` class objects. But your current action method code is sending a list of `User` entity (the entity class which is totally different than your view model class). That is the reason you are getting this type mismatch error.

You should send the correct type from your action method. You may use projection on your linq statement to get a collection of AccountViewModel from the `db.Users` collection.

```
var accountViewModelList = db.Users
                             .Select(x=> new AccountViewModel { Id=x.Id }) 
                             .ToList();
return View(accountViewModelList);
```

The above code will basically create a list of `AccountViewModel` objects and read each User entity object's `Id` property value and assign it to the corresponding view model object's `Id` property. If you want more properties in your view, you should map those as well.

For example, if you have a FirstName property in both your entity class and view model, you may do this,

```
var accountViewModelList = db.Users
                             .Select(x=> new AccountViewModel { 
                                                               Id=x.Id,
                                                               FirstName = x.FirstName }) 
                             .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

in your controller, use this to return the model to the view

```
return View(avm.user.AsEnumerable);
```

your db query returns a IQueryable,
you did put the ToList on the whole model, not on the user field